# C++: unique_ptr not initializing correctly

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

`myMain.cpp`:

```
#include <memory>
#include "myClass.h"

static std::unique_ptr<myClass> classPtr; // Error thrown here
...
```

I am initializing in global scope because loading all the data into the properties of this class takes a while, so I'd like to do it once and have that data persist until I give an explicit command to delete it (`classPtr.reset(nullptr)`).

When I try to compile this: `g++ myMain.cpp -o myMain.o` I get: `error: expected initializer before '<' token`.

**Why am I getting this error?**

I've defined `myClass` in `myClass.h` and `myClass.cpp`; I think the error has to do with the constructor. I've simplified code & included only the important lines below.

`myClass.h`:

```
class myClass {
    std::string dataPath;
    std::vector<double> data;
public:
    myClass(std::string P = "./path/to/data-file.csv");
    ~myClass() {}
    const double findPercentile(double percentile = 0.0);
}
```

EDIT: Following tip from @FrançoisAndrieux I have fixed my constructor.

`myClass.cpp`:

```
myClass::myClass(const std::string P) : 
            dataPath(P) {
    // read data-sets into class member variables
}
```

Comment: Note related to your question : you declare your constructor `myClass(std::string)` but implement it as `myClass(const std::string)`. You define the argument to have the default value `"./path/to/data-file.csv"` but then you disregard the argument and always initialize with the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two significant problems:

1. since you are using gcc 4.8.5, remember to use the flag `-std=c++11` otherwise `std::unique_ptr` will not be available.
2. end your class definition with a `;`. The semi-colon is required in C/C++ when declaring types. Because you did not use a `;`, you did not declare `myClass` as a type, and so it follows that the line `static std::unique_ptr<myClass> classPtr;` will produce an error since `myClass` is not a valid type.

Comment: @VladislavMartin Your example does not illustrate how you are initializing your `unique_ptr`. It would be important to show it if that's what's causing you problems.

Comment: I cannot get the updated example to produce the error you described. You will need to supply a [MCVE]. Make a short self contained example that, when compiled and executed, produces the error you observe.

Comment: @VladislavMartin You have not. The example has a few errors but none that I found that could produce the error you described. Fixing them, I am able to compile the example without error. Take the example you provided, compile it by itself as a new project. If you can reproduce the error, indicate which line is causing it and which compiler you are using.

Comment: All the errors I'm getting are related to the `unique_ptr` not being initialized correctly. I am compiling with `g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 (Read Hat 4.8.5-4)` on a Linux machine. The error is NOT thrown in the class definition - it's thrown in a source file that included the class, on line 4 (I've added a comment in my question showing where).

Comment: Are you using a flag such as `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Class definitions need to end with `;`.

Comment: Ok - can you update your answer with those two notes: 1) use the `-std=c++11` and 2) your most recent comment? I'll accept it - you've fixed the problem. I guess it's to be expected that most mistakes made when writing C++ are silly over-sights.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization of your `data` member should either be

```
data(std::vector<double>())
```

Or more simply

```
data()
```